# Running Shell Script in Cloud Scheduler

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

Can we Schedule Shell Script to run in Cloud Scheduler?

In the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) i am seeing 3 targets HTTP,Pub/Sub,App Engine HTTP. Are there any updates in this regard?

Thanks in Adnavce.

Comment: Have you considered translate your shell script in a python script (Cloud Functions) and use the HTTP trigger?

Comment: Thanks for the response Alvaro, i have gone through this guide (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/schedule-export) whcih says the same thing but i just wanted to know whether i could run shell script anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to trigger shell script as-is with Cloud Scheduler. At Google (and Google Cloud) all is API, and Cloud Scheduler can only call an API.

Therefore, I contributed on this [opensource project](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-firestore-backup) months ago, and I discovered a way to plug a shell script on a webserver and then to deploy it on Cloud Run.

You can get inspiration from it, and then create a cloud scheduler, which call your Cloud Run with your wrapped shell script